# Octave help command error: __makeinfo__: could not create temporary file

Tags: file, octave, temporary

I'm using Octave on win 7.
When I type 'help' command on prompt,

ex)

```
>> help eye
```

error occur and says

```
error: __makeinfo__: could not create temporary file
error: called from
    __makeinfo__ at line 122 column 7
    help at line 102 column 24
```

What can I do?
Is there any package or something for using help command right?

Comment: how did you install octave?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - by download and execute 'octave-5.1.0-w64-installer.exe'

Comment: Anything unusual? Anti-virus denying access to temp. Please try to manually create a file in temdir from octave and report what happens

Comment: @Andy - I made some txt file in octave/tmp folder, but It just worked. No error happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentor of Coursera machine learnig course solved my problem!
His comment is as below.

> It sounds like your Octave installation was not successful.
>
> Be sure you downloaded the correct word size (32 or 64 bits) for your
>   operating system, and also you should download the Windows executable
>   installer.
>
> For a different reason, you'll do better with version 4.4.1, because
>   5.1.0 has a defect in one of the functions. The defect makes the exercises difficult to use.

So I installed version 4.4.1, and everything is fine!